# SubSonic Batch insert

Tags: c#, activerecord, subsonic, transactions, subsonic3

I am familiar with SubSonic 2.2 and am coming up to speed with 3.0 and am unsure of the best way to do something.  I have a CSV file that I am parsing and then inserting the records into the database.  I want to be able to process the batch of inserts all at once.  IE I would like to parse through the records and add them to a List insertAll and if all records in the import pass validation I would like to Insert them all at once.  Doing something like Repo.Insert(insertAll).  What options do I have in SubSonic 3.0.  Are Transactions my only way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Add repository method to insert an IEnumerable list in a single transaction so you can do something like the following:

```
List<MyObject> = myObjects new List<MyObject>();

// Populate your MyObject List from your CSV file

SubSonicRepository<MyObject> repo = new SubSonicRepository<MyObject>(new MyDB());
repo.Add(myObjects);
```